# How is the calculation of papa and punya is being done

Tags: karma

How Dharma, Adharma and Papa , Punya calculation is done?

Why a person doesn't get his results of karma immediately?

Comment: Is this question exact duplicate with two other duplicate questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can relate every  aspect of our religious views to science and environment.If one has a guilty memory or others have a knowledge of his guilty actions it affects him naturally because of forces in the environment.
These forces either arise from one's conscience or from the society.Its because of forces from society many innocents were punished in the history(the false accusations all happened) even they haven't committed any sin. And also its evident naturally in the political world sinners living a good life. Above all any punishment or reward can be given only when one is alive on the earth(to do any good to rest of the people too).And I have ruled out the concepts of heaven and hell because one ruining lives of people on earth though suffers in hell(as some people say)his suffering in hell is of no use to the living people. A sinner's suffering on this very earth will at least be useful for reducing crimes in the future.So the recordings of Papa and Punya are lying in our hands and the caring and awareness we have on the society.Actually it's all psychology and practical life.From your point of view...This society is too large for one to get the results of karma immediately...it's like a big domino...after a natural and enough flow of time one will get the result eventually... Everything takes its own time to happen.